# Are there any ways to disable ctrl-i at mac's default terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, key-bindings

I'm a mac user and use mac's default terminal app. Are there any ways to disable ctr-i at mac's default terminal? Ctrl-i conflicts my vim and tmux shortcut. I don't need to use ctrl-i binding as the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ctrl+I</kbd> (whether <kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>I</kbd> does not matter) is the <kbd>TAB</kbd> character, which you probably need.  It is not a key which is set in `Terminal`'s *preferences*, so (while you *could* add a keyboard shortcut to something different), it is not something that you could *disable*.